# Parse and concatenate two columns

Tags: scala, parsing, concatenation

I am trying to parse and concatenate two columns at the same time using the following expression:

```
val part : RDD[(String)] = sc.textFile("hdfs://xxx:8020/user/sample_head.csv")
                    .map{line => val row = line split ','
                    (row(1), row(2)).toString}
```

which returns something like:

```
Array((AAA,111), (BBB,222),(CCC,333))
```

But how could I directly get:

```
Array(AAA, 111 , BBB, 222, CCC, 333)
```

Comment: You're explicitly turning it into a `"(AAA, 111)"` form with the `.toString` so it's not clear what you actually want. But probably `.flatMap{cols => cols split  ',';Array(cols(1), cols(2))}` would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your toString() on a tuple really doesn't make much sense to me. Can you explain why do you want to create strings from tuples and then split them again later?

If you are willing to map each row into a list of elements instead of a stringified tuple of elements, you could rewrite

```
(row(1), row(2)).toString
```

to

```
List(row(1), row(2))
```

and simply flatten the resulting list:

```
val list = List("0,aaa,111", "1,bbb,222", "2,ccc,333")

val tuples = list.map{ line => 
  val row = line split ','
  List(row(1), row(2))}

val flattenedTuples = tuples.flatten

println(flattenedTuples) // prints List(aaa, 111, bbb, 222, ccc, 333)
```

Note that what you are trying to achieve involves flattening and can be done using flatMap, but not using just map. You need to either flatMap directly, or do map followed by flatten like I showed you (I honestly don't remember if Spark supports flatMap). Also, as you can see I used a List as a more idiomatic Scala data structure, but it's easily convertible to Array and vice versa.

Comment: "(I honestly don't remember if Spark supports flatMap)". It does.